# error when uploading string with special characters

Tags: php, special-characters

i am uploading a string which has special characters

Example

```
$what = Fay King suggests â€˜Miss Airheartâ€™ as name for â€˜Lady Lindy'"
```

and it uploads as

```
Fay King suggests â¬ ÜMiss Airheartâ¬ "! as name for â¬
```

What should i do to avoid this decoding error?

I have tried to use utf8_encode on the string, but it did not work out.

Comment: You're uploading a string? Also; what type of error are you getting? Paste it here.

Comment: @WayneWhitty modified the question

Comment: Are you "uploading" throug a form?. Through GET or POST?. How do you capture the string?

Comment: @TeofiloIsraelVizcainoRodrig: i am using php to access a excel sheet which has the $what string and eventually i upload this string into a form of other website.

Comment: Then check for the encoding in the other site

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure, that the page that uploads the string and the one that displays the string have the same text encoding, e.g. this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

**In general, each page of your WebApp should have only and only one text encoding set.**

Answer (score -1):

have you tried a simple urlencode()?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php