# PHP characters error

Tags: php, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error when uploading string with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384872/error-when-uploading-string-with-special-characters)

I have a string say

```
$what = suggests â€˜
```

i am not able to upload $what as it is, it throws decode error

I also tried using url_encode, url_decode, htmlspecialcharacters,utf8 etc.,but for no use.

url_encode, url_decode makes it as following:

```
suggests ?? but not as suggests â€˜
```

What should i do for $what to be as

```
suggests â€˜
```

Comment: Where does the string come from? What do you mean by "upload" and what decode error are you getting when running what code? **Edit:** I just noticed that you already asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384872/error-when-uploading-string-with-special-characters) before, were asked for the same clarifications, didn't provide them, but received *two upvotes* for the question. My faith in this community is eroding a bit every time I see something like this.

Comment: What's the charset/coding you are using in your text editor?

Comment: I am fetching the string the from a excel sheet

Comment: @MMM do you the mean the header i have used in my php file??

Comment: I mean the coding you use in your editor. Your text editor encodes your text file (php script) using certain coding (like utf-8). It should match your header.

Comment: @Pekka Decode error: the server replies just as decode error and when  uploaded using url_encode it stores successfully with 210 success message. Upload: i upload all the content in the excel to a form of a website and store the reply in another excel sheet

Comment: @Pekka : And sorry for eroding your faith this community requires ppl like you. i myself voted for closing this question. Cheers

Comment: Do edit your original question then, and describe *in detail* what you do (including some code). Something goes wrong in the encoding somewhere along the way - the only way to find out where is to know exactly what goes on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Hixie’s decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder), it’s easy to check that â€˜ is the UTF-8 encoded representation of U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (‘) misinterpreted as separate bytes if were windows-1252 encoded. It’s more difficult to say why this happens—insufficient information about context and code.